# What does a network interface mean from TCP/IP stack perspective?

Tags: networking

I wanted to know the relationship between a logical network interface (e.g. eth0 displayed by ifconfig in Linux) and the TCP/IP stack.

My understanding is a network interface represents the Data Link Layer in the TCP/IP stack. And the traffic goes through the interface is frames.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I found this good reference http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPIPArchitectureandtheTCPIPModel-2.htm

Answer (score -2):

The actual, physical interface is layer-1.  Layer-1 sends and receives bits on the wire.

The logical interface is layer-2.  Layer-2 sends and receives frames.

TCP/IP starts at layer-3 for IP, and layer-4 for TCP, UDP, etc.

TCP/IP is independent of the lower layers.

Comment: That is one perspective. TCP/IP can run on other physical/logical interfaces like frame relay, HDLC, ATM, SONET, FDDI, token ring, PPP, etc., each having their own, different layer-2. Other layer-3 protocols besides IP can run on top of these other layer-1/layer-2 stacks, too. That means that TCP/IP is independent of the lower layers.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I'll cancel the down vote later.